# Не получается сделать скрипт для переключения "Tabs Menu" Node.js Electron

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Суть в том что по умолчанию открывается "tab1", это является начальной страницей. При переключении между ними всё содержимое "tab1" пропадает и не появляются другие. Как я понял проблема в том что не присваивается какой-то класс.

(HTML)

```
<div class="tabs_box">
    <div class="tab" id="tab1">
      <p>
      <a class="zagolovok">О НАШЕМ СООБЩЕСТВЕ</a>
      </p>
      <img src="Rectangle 89.svg" class="back-img"/>
      <p>Наше ролевое сообщество существует с 2014 года, еще тогда команда разработчиков задумалась о создании проекта, на котором будет просто и комфортно играть. Сложная цель для SA:MP сообщества, в целом, подталкивала нас на развитие, улучшение и пропаганды в массы ролевого процесса. Сложный путь, до 2018 года, был полон сюрпризов, крахов, падений, не стыковок. Уже тогда проект стабильно держал планку в 300 человек, обладая достаточно сложной UCP регистрацией. Вместе с всеобщим признанием появилось и всеобщее недовольство.
      В 2017 году, а если быть точным - в новый 2018 год. После небольшой паузы проект начинает новую жизнь, преследуя все ту же цель, но с большими амбициями и слаженной командой, которая пополнилась хорошими специалистами и людьми в целом. Мы решили не брать во внимание прошлые заслуги проекта и начали строить игру с самого начала, привлекая игровые сообщества, новых игроков и соратников.</p>
      <p>Gambit RolePlay буквально за 3 месяца заслужил признание многих игроков, сервер в пики забит онлайном в 500+ человек, единый город, оживленные улицы и качественная атмосфера придают данному проекту вид действительно оживленного, американского города. Каждый месяц мы работаем над улучшением, продвижением и зарабатываем признание нашей аудитории.</p>        
      <p>Главная цель проекта — это привлечение как можно большего количества игроков отыгрывать ролевой режим, и познать все прелести и плюсы данного игрового процесса. Ведь свобода действия, атмосфера и адекватная аудитория — это лучшее, что может быть для проекта, особенно когда все это находится в одном месте!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="tab2">
      <p>Наше ролевое сообщество существует с 2014 года, еще тогда команда разработчиков задумалась о создании проекта, на котором будет просто и комфортно играть. Сложная цель для SA:MP сообщества, в целом, подталкивала нас на развитие, улучшение и пропаганды в массы ролевого процесса. Сложный путь, до 2018 года, был полон сюрпризов, крахов, падений, не стыковок. Уже тогда проект стабильно держал планку в 300 человек, обладая достаточно сложной UCP регистрацией. Вместе с всеобщим признанием появилось и всеобщее недовольство.<br>

        В 2017 году, а если быть точным - в новый 2018 год. После небольшой паузы проект начинает новую жизнь, преследуя все ту же цель, но с большими амбициями и слаженной командой, которая пополнилась хорошими специалистами и людьми в целом. Мы решили не брать во внимание прошлые заслуги проекта и начали строить игру с самого начала, привлекая игровые сообщества, новых игроков и соратников.
        
        Gambit RolePlay буквально за 3 месяца заслужил признание многих игроков, сервер в пики забит онлайном в 500+ человек, единый город, оживленные улицы и качественная атмосфера придают данному проекту вид действительно оживленного, американского города. Каждый месяц мы работаем над улучшением, продвижением и зарабатываем признание нашей аудитории.
        
        Главная цель проекта — это привлечение как можно большего количества игроков отыгрывать ролевой режим, и познать все прелести и плюсы данного игрового процесса. Ведь свобода действия, атмосфера и адекватная аудитория — это лучшее, что может быть для проекта, особенно когда все это находится в одном месте!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab" id="tab3">
      <p>Вкладка  ролевое сообщество существует с 2014 года, еще тогда команда разработчиков задумалась о создании проекта, на котором будет просто и комфортно играть. Сложная цель для SA:MP сообщества, в целом, подталкивала нас на развитие, улучшение и пропаганды в массы ролевого процесса. Сложный путь, до 2018 года, был полон сюрпризов, крахов, падений, не стыковок. Уже тогда проект стабильно держал планку в 300 человек, обладая достаточно сложной UCP регистрацией. Вместе с всеобщим признанием появилось и всеобщее недовольство.

        В 2017 году, а если быть точным - в новый 2018 год. После небольшой паузы проект начинает новую жизнь, преследуя все ту же цель, но с большими амбициями и слаженной командой, которая пополнилась хорошими специалистами и людьми в целом. Мы решили не брать во внимание прошлые заслуги проекта и начали строить игру с самого начала, привлекая игровые сообщества, новых игроков и соратников.
        
        Gambit RolePlay буквально за 3 месяца заслужил признание многих игроков, сервер в пики забит онлайном в 500+ человек, единый город, оживленные улицы и качественная атмосфера придают данному проекту вид действительно оживленного, американского города. Каждый месяц мы работаем над улучшением, продвижением и зарабатываем признание нашей аудитории.
        
        Главная цель проекта — это привлечение как можно большего количества игроков отыгрывать ролевой режим, и познать все прелести и плюсы данного игрового процесса. Ведь свобода действия, атмосфера и адекватная аудитория — это лучшее, что может быть для проекта, особенно когда все это находится в одном месте!</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="switch-buttons">
    <div class="tabs_menu">
      <a id="bttn1" href="#tab1">Описание проекта</a>
      <a id="bttn2" href="#tab2">О сообществе</a>
      <a id="bttn3" class="active" href="#tab3">Ответы на вопросы</a>
      <a id="bttn4" href="#">Группа ВКонтакте</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

(CSS)

```
    .tabs_box{
    -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 15px;
    
    position: absolute;
    width: 710px;
    height: 459px;
    left: 336px;
    top: 105px;
    
    /* White */
    
    background: #F4F4F4;
    border-radius: 7px;
  }
  #tab2, #tab3{
    display: none;
  }
  .tab{
    position: static;
    width: 678px;
    height: 465px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 198px;
    
    font-family: Rubik;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    /* or 133% */
    
    /* Gray/Dark */
    
    color: #454545;
    
    /* Inside Auto Layout */
    flex: none;
    order: 2;
    flex-grow: 0;
    margin: 0px 15px;   
  }
```

(JS)

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('.tabs_menu a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.tabs_menu .active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var tab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.tab').not(tab).css({'display': 'none'});
    $('tab').fadeIn(400);
  });
});
```

[image: Кусок кода исчез, добавлю картинку]

Comment: `$('tab').fadeIn(400);` - здесь, скорее всего лишние кавычки, должно быть  `$(tab).fadeIn(400);`